# How can I establish a UDP connection from AWS game server to Smartphone Unity Game

Tags: c#, udp

How does one connect to a client from a remote server using UDP if all we can get is the global IP (the router's IP)?

I am getting the global IP of the client using the code:

```
string externalIp = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
```

Is there a way to get a client's local IP? Also to which IP address should my server connect when using UDP?

Comment: Why do you want to connect to the client from the server?

Comment: I need to send the server's game state to all the clients.

Comment: Why not start the connection from the client?

Comment: Because I thought UDP was only one way connection?

Comment: It’s connectionless, but it’s still two way in a way. In any case, if you send a packet from the client, the router will NAT it and reserve a port for it. Then the server can send packets to that port and the client will receive them.

Comment: Ok, so how do I figure out the port the router reserves for the client?

Comment: By the packet that the client sends to the server. It has the originating address and port in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171736/discussion-between-djooryabi-and-sami-kuhmonen).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is to use a game service like GameSparks to send TCP and UDP port information from my server to each game client. The game client would then connect to the TCP and UDP port which would give the server knowledge of the client's endpoint. This way a two way communication can be established with both TCP and UDP.